# Which way will be more efficient ? (Java Android Programming)

Tags: java, android, performance

In my app I need to change the value of an integer variable . The way I have changed this  , like this

```
  int variable; 

    if (condition) {
        variable= 1;                
    } 
    else if (condition) {
        variable= 2 ;               
    }
   ..........
   ..........
    else {
        variable=3;
    }
```

Or shpould I declare an array  and change the value of variable like this

```
int variable; 

    if (condition) {
        variable= array[0];                
    } 
    else if (condition) {
        variable= array[1];               
    }
   ..........
   ..........
    else {
        variable=0;
    }
```

Which the more performance optimized way ? Or both do the same ?

Comment: I feel the first one is good choice. Because array will have more complexity and from above example I feel there is no need of array,in any case.

Comment: That totally depends on whether the values that you are assigning are static like 1,2,3 or are in an array and dynamic.. Actually both have different utility depending on the scenario

Comment: There will not be much difference in efficiency with the code you have posted

Comment: If your values are fixed then you can define final int variables!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the switch statement instead for more clarity and fast access if there is too much else if ladder

Answer (score 0):

If your values are constants and simple integers then the first choice is more preferable as that would avoid the overhead of creating arrays and thus saving some memory for you. :)

Also, for switching between the conditions you can consider @henrycharles answer as switch case at times prove more efficient than if-else.

Answer (score 0):

The performance will slightly be worse in the second case I assume (but you will not notice it). I mean you have to bring additional variables to the stack - the array itself. You will need more memory as well to create and keep the array.

But because you have if/else branching, a missed if/else branch will have a bigger impact then array or not-array. **Either way** I would not worry too much about it, this difference will be in the order of ns.

Of course you call always measure- but micro-benchmarking Java is not always easy.